# My camera turned invisible

Tags: 3d-view, camera, scene, outliner

It might be a dumb question but I didn't find the answer anywhere on the internet.

I really don't understand why my camera is all of a sudden invisible in my scene. I know it is there when I push <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> it goes to the cameras view but when I push it again and go back into the scene its gone along with the center point. So far I have only tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

The camera is selected here but I cant see the black outlining
[image: The camera is selected here but I cant see the black outlining]

Comment: Maybe you zoomed in to a point where your camera boundaries are outside of your viewport?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 3D View properties region <kbd>N</kbd> key, to the right of the screen, you ticked the option *Only Render* (visible in your screenshot).

This makes only visible objects with actual renderable geometry visible in the viewport. The camera object, being an abstraction of a virtual object not visible in a final image, becomes hidden away.

Comment: In case you can't find that option: it's in the "Display" group right next to the vase in your image, the top option in that group.

Comment: question: since blender got updated where did the display tab move

Comment: @michael it is now distributed under the popover menus in the 3D View header

Answer (score 3):

I expect you accidentally made the camera invisible in the view port.  To fix this, go into the *Outliner*, find the camera, and click the little closed eye by it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the image closely, I see that you have objects in every Blender layer, but only one layer is visible. I suspect if you find the layer in which you have the camera placed, and make that visible, too, you will find your camera.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. If you are on a second layer your camera could be on the first.